# Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'x' is being used without being initialized

Tags: c++

Пишу программу. Код, та часть на которой ломается:

```
int main()
{
    int *x;
    x[0]=1;
}
```

Выдает ошибку при выполнении:

```
Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'x' is being used without being initialized
```

Что я не так делаю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Указатель вы создали, а где выделение памяти?

Comment: точно) спасибо большое, надо ж так, давно просто ничего не писала

Answer (score 1):

А что эта "прога" должна делать?
В такой редакции имеет место попытка записать int(1) по заранее неизвестному адресу.

Comment: нет, я просто вставила сюда кусочек где ломалось. А вообще, в итоге надо запрограммировать первую интерполяционную формулу Гауса для равноотстоящих узлов.